# Is it possible to create a Point Light Shadowmap with only 1 Texture and 1 Vertexshader?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, shadow, hlsl

I was wondering if it would be somehow possible to reduce the need for 6 shadowmaps (front, back,top,right,left,down) with normal Projectionmatrix to only a single one, using some Vertex Shader trickery.
Basicly I want to somehow manipulate the vertex (or pixel) shader, so it turns the final render in some sort of 360 view around the pointlight, and stores it in a single texture.
I would of course also need a way to reverse the whole thing in order to actually render the shadow.

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't use a cube map?

Comment: Are you aware of how geometry shaders are used to render to a layer and the specific cube map face in that layer? Also, there is no "trickery" involved here - it's all standard stuff.